# Running QtQuickTest unit tests

Tags: qt, unit-testing, qml

The [QtQuickTest docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qttest-testcase.html) don't make it clear how to refer to other components, run tests on them, etc.

It is relatively simple to write a `tst_foo.qml`, define a GUI object and a `TestCase` inside it that runs functions called `test_*` that checks aspects of your GUI object, but that is not a real-world situation. You would have your components to test in files that are **not** called `tst_*`. So my questions are:

- The tester automatically runs all QML files called `tst_*.qml`. This implies that there are **separate** qml file with unit tests. But so far, I have only been able to do what [this person](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34747483/648159) does: rename the QML object you want to test to `tst_foo.qml` and define a `TestCase` in it. So the subsequent questions are:
- Are you supposed to define a `TestCase` inside the GUI element and call it from a `tst_foo.qml` file? If so, how?
- Or are you supposed to define a `TestCase` inside `tst_foo.qml` that refers to your GUI component? If so, how?

Another issue is that the QML loader for the unit test seems to use `QQuickView`, so it can only load items derived from `QQuickItem`. So how do you test an `ApplicationWindow`? In this case, renaming your QML file to `tst_mainApp.qml` doesn't even work: "*QQuickView only supports loading of root objects that derive from QQuickItem.*"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are you supposed to define a TestCase inside the GUI element and call it from a tst_foo.qml file? If so, how?

No, definitely not.

> Or are you supposed to define a TestCase inside tst_foo.qml that refers to your GUI component? If so, how?

It depends on where the GUI object is. If it has its own import, you can use the `-imports` argument to the test executable, as documented [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquicktest-index.html#running-tests). You can also use the `IMPORTPATH` `qmake` variable in your test's `.pro` file, as mentioned there. Your test might look like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtTest 1.0

import MyImport 1.0

TestCase {
    id: testCase
    name: "Untitled"
    width: 200
    height: 200
    when: windowShown

    Component {
        id: myItemComponent

        MyItem {
            // ...
        }
    }

    function test_stuff() {
        var myItem = myItemComponent.createObject(testCase);
        verify(myItem);

        // test myItem

        myItem.destroy();
    }
}
```

This works fine if you want to test a custom item like a button that you wrote. This is how most of Qt Quick Controls' tests work, for example.

However, if you want to test an *application* in the same manner as a user would interact with it, you have two options (that I know of):

1. Use a testing tool like [Squish](https://www.froglogic.com/squish/gui-testing/index.php). I haven't used this, but in terms of getting as close as possible to user interaction with an application, it would be hard to beat. It works by recording input from the developer, which is then replayed "on" your application whenever the tests are run.
2. In my latest project, I decided to try testing the exact same QML used in the application. For this, you need to write your test in C++, and the C++/QML for the application must be built twice: once if you're building the application, once if you're building the test. It works quite well, but my application is not that large, so it doesn't take long to build.

The second option is probably more powerful, as you have a lot of flexibility when writing tests in C++, but it requires a bit more knowledge of Qt.

> Another issue is that the QML loader for the unit test seems to use QQuickView, so it can only load items derived from QQuickItem. So how do you test an ApplicationWindow?

You'd need to write a C++ test for this using [Qt Test](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtest-overview.html), and then use `QQmlEngine` or `QQmlApplicationEngine` to load the UI. See [this test](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols2.git/tree/tests/auto/focus/tst_focus.cpp?h=5.15#n99) for an example. However, you shouldn't need to test `ApplicationWindow`, unless you're going for the approach I'm using that I mentioned above.

Comment: Seems clear enough, except that I shouldn't need to test `ApplicationWindow`? I want to test more than just the components; I want to test if an application actually does what it needs to do (functional tests), not just if some custom GUI element works. I'm not averse to writing C++, so is that indeed a manageable way to go?

Comment: That's what I meant by the "unless you're going for the approach I'm using that I mentioned above". That is a whole other answer in its own right though (to explain how to set up the projects, C++, etc.). It's definitely manageable to write tests in C++.